# MatTableDataSource how to get sorted order of data set?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Let say I have a `mat-table` with `mat-sort-header` and `matSort` to enable the sorting, and with `[dataSource]="tableDetails"`. After I fetch the data into `sampleData`, I initialize the table with following:

```
this.tableDetails = new MatTableDataSource(this.sampleData);
```

I have the sample data as below, and in it's default order:

```
sampleData = 
[
    {'id':1, 'name':'item 1'},
    {'id':2, 'name':'item 2'},
    {'id':3, 'name':'item 3'}
]
```

I can get the first item with `this.tableDetails.data[0]`. Now if I use `mat-sort-header` to sort the table with `id` in descending order, the first item displayed will be `{'id':3, 'name':'item 3'}`, but `this.tableDetails.data[0]` still return the `{'id':1, 'name':'item 1'}`. I notice that mat-sort-header will not change the original order of the datasource. Any idea on how to get the sorted order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the dataSource you have a sortData method which you can use to get sorted table data.

[MatTableDataSource sortData  method](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource)

> Gets a sorted copy of the data array based on the state of the MatSort. Called after changes are made to the filtered data or when sort changes are emitted from MatSort. By default, the function retrieves the active sort and its direction and compares data by retrieving data using the sortingDataAccessor. May be overridden for a custom implementation of data ordering.

```
this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.data, this.dataSource.sort)
```

Comment: after I call this method, the original data set `this.dataSource.data` will be sorted, is there a way to get sorted copy without changing the order the of original data set?

Comment: You can create a copy of the data and work on it instead of on the main dataSource.
backupDataSource = [ ... this.dataSource] etc. 

Did I properly understand the issue? I'm not sure If it's what you meant

Answer (score 1):

Solution found here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11670

```
this.dataSource.connect().subscribe(d => this.renderedData = d);
```

In fact, what i did was that (recreate the table with the new row order):

```
this.dataSource.connect().subscribe(data: any) => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the new position o pass to a new array after filter sort the table;

```
 // let yourNewData = [ ... this.dataSource.filteredData]

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    console.log(this.dataSource.filteredData[0])
  }
```